# Nginx vs PHP 7 Cli $_SERVER[request_uri] differences?

Tags: php, firefox, nginx, php-7

[image: Nginx vs PHP 7 Cli $_SERVER[request_uri] differences]

The function in question is "get_uri". When executed in the CLI I get "nope" which is the false "if" response. However, when run inside the browser (firefox) I get the "if" true response. Is this a bug or am I doing something incredibly stupid?

Comment: What do you think a URI is and why would you expect one on the command line?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is ___Its not a bug___ so therefore **.......**

Comment: The URI I am referencing is part of the url...Sure, I have access to $_SERVER inside php when being executed through Firefox. However, I assumed that since php has access to that $_SERVER variable that the accompanying CLI could access it as well. Seems your both telling me that it cannot.